# Unwanted Cumulative Delay in Nodejs Requests

Tags: node.js, linux, typescript, request, centos

I have a NodeJs app hosted on Centos.
Every 1 minute it gets a list from the server.
setInterval works fine, but its response takes longer and longer.

request 1: 13:00:00 , response 1: ~13:00:01
request 2: 13:01:00 , response 2: ~13:01:10
request 3: 13:02:00 , response 3: ~13:02:30
request 4: 13:03:00 , response 3: ~13:04:00
...

My code:

```
var getListFromServer = () => {  
    
    let fromDate = Date.now(),
        toDate = fromDate + (10 * 60 * 1000); // until next 10 minutes
    
    let path = `https://mywebsite.com/api/getList?fromDate=${fromDate}&toDate=${toDate}`;
    
    request({url: path, json: true}, (error, response, list) => {

        if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) 
            return console.log('ERROR: ', error);

        console.log('DATA...');

    });
}

setInterval( getListFromServer , 60 * 1000); // run every 1 minute
```

Comment: If you are using nodeJs then you can use promises instead of callback. 
change Date.now() to new Date(); and toDate = new Date(fromDate.getTime() + 10 * 60 * 1000);